# Problemas ao deletar via ajax com laravel

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

Estou tendo problema para efetivar uma deleção com `Laravel 5.3`. Ao submeter o ajax ele simplesmente não está me retornando nada.

Meu `JavaScript` está assim:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });

function excluir(id){
    swal({   
        title: "Tem certeza?",   
        text: "Você não será capaz de recuperar este item!",   
        type: "warning",   
        showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
        confirmButtonText: "Sim, excluir!",   
        cancelButtonText: "Não, voltar!",   
        closeOnConfirm: false,   
        closeOnCancel: false 
    }, function(isConfirm){   
        if (isConfirm) {
             var url = location.href; //pega endereço que esta no navegador
            url = url.split("/"); //quebra o endeço de acordo com a / (barra)

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url[2] + "/clientes/delete",
                data: id,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    alert( data );
                    swal("Excluido!", "Seu item foi excluido com sucesso. "+id, "success"); 

                }
            });
        } else {     
            swal("Cancelado", "Seu item está seguro", "error");   
        } 
    });
};
```

Meu `Controller` assim:

```
public function delete(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    $id = $request->input('id');
    return $id;
}
```

Porém nada acontece, tentei utilizar um app para enviar um POST e verificar o retorno, e o erro que ele me apresentou foi devido ao CSRF_TOKEN porém adicionei a primeira linha no meu `javascript` e de nada adiantou.

Minha folha de `rotas` está assim:

```
Route::singularResourceParameters();

Route::auth();

// ROTAS DE DELEÇÃO

Route::post('/clientes/delete', [
    'uses' => 'ClienteController@delete',
    'as' => 'produtos.delete'
    ]);

// FIM DE ROTAS DE DELEÇÃO

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('clientes', 'ClienteController');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem erros de configuração que compromete o envio da requisição via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel). `$.ajaxSetup` estava errado a chave da `headers` como descrito [na própria documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) do framework [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
     }
});
```

Nesse caso em especifico é melhor trabalhar com [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) do [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) e também na passagem do valor atribua sempre `{'id' : id}` para que seja reconhecimento pelo [`Request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests):

```
function excluir(id)
{
    swal({   
        title: "Tem certeza?",   
        text: "Você não será capaz de recuperar este item!",   
        type: "warning",   
        showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
        confirmButtonText: "Sim, excluir!",   
        cancelButtonText: "Não, voltar!",   
        closeOnConfirm: false,   
        closeOnCancel: false 
    }, function(isConfirm){ 

        if (isConfirm) 
        {
            $.post('{{route("produtos.delete")}}', {'id':id}, function (result)
            {
               alert(result); 
               swal("Excluido!", 
                    "Seu item foi excluido com sucesso. " + result,
                    "success");            
            });             
        } 
        else 
        {     
            swal("Cancelado", "Seu item está seguro", "error");   
        }
    });
};
```

***Referencias:***

- [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
- [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)